# Finding the first intersection of a horizontal ray with many vertical line segments in $O(\log n)$ time

Tags: algorithms

Design a data structure and a search algorithm to solve the following problem. It should be
able to answer the query in O(log2 n) time. A high-level description of your data structure,
the search algorithm, and its running time are sufficient.

You are to store a set of n vertical segments, where each segment extends from a point
pi = (xi; yi) down to the x-axis. You may assume that all coordinates are positive. The query consists of a single point q = (qx; qy). Imagine that you shoot a bullet horizontally to the left from q. Return the rst vertical line segment in the data structure that is hit by this bullet path. If no segment is hit, then return null.

It is a homework question and I am trying to solve it. What I came up is that first I sort the data tuples acccording to their X values, using this we would know which of the lines are closest. Then iterating from the maximum value of x to 0 in x axis we keep on checking y whether the Y coordinate is greater or equal to that of the points Y coordinate. 

Now how can sorting be done in just log n time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, to achieve $O(\log n)$ time complexity for a search problem, you need some kind of [*divide and conquer* strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) such as [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Sorting by $x_i$ is not enough, as this merely allows you to find the first candidate with $O(\log n)$. You still need need to do a linear search for the actual solution which has a worst-case complexity of $O(n)$.

Hint: Put your $p_i$ into a tree. If you add the right information to the nodes, then you can (almost) always easily decide which child has to contain the solution.

Solution:

> Use a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and make each node correspond to a contiguous subspace, i.e. it contains all points with $a \leq x_i \leq b$. Choose the subspaces so that any two children bisect the space of its parent.
>  Add an $X_i$ and $Y_i$ to each node, where $X_i$ is the smallest $x_j$ of the children and $Y_i$ the largest $y_j$. In other words: The non-leaf nodes represent [bounding rectangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of their children.
>  Then you search recursively for the intersection with the line through $q$. Each node with $Y_i \geq q_y$ contains at least one intersection. Use $X_i$ to decide which of two children to inspect. You sometimes need to backtrack, because all intersections in a subtree are to the right of $q_x$, but that can happen at most once.